# What is the endpoint calculation in the Xiaolin Wu algorithm doing?

Tags: graphics, geometry, raster, antialiasing, bresenham

The [Xiaolin Wu algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm) draws an anti-aliased line between two points. The points can be at sub-pixel, i.e. non-integer coordinates. I'll assume the reader is familiar with the algorithm and just recall the important features. We loop across the major (longer) axis of the line, let's say it's the x-axis, basically proceeding column-by-column. In each column we color two pixels. The computation is equivalent to this: place a 1x1 square centered on the line, at the point whose x coordinate is the center of the the given column of pixels. Let's call it S. If we think of each pixel as a 1x1 square in the plane, we now calculate the area of intersection between S and each of the two pixels it straddles, and use those areas as the intensities with which to color each pixel.

That's nice and clear, but what is going on with the calculations for the endpoints? Because the endpoints can be at non-integer positions, they have to be treated as a special case. Here's the pseudocode from the linked Wikipedia article for handling the first endpoint x0, y0:

```
// handle first endpoint
xend := round(x0)
yend := y0 + gradient * (xend - x0)
xgap := rfpart(x0 + 0.5)
xpxl1 := xend // this will be used in the main loop
ypxl1 := ipart(yend)
plot(ypxl1,   xpxl1, rfpart(yend) * xgap)
plot(ypxl1+1, xpxl1,  fpart(yend) * xgap)
```

I edited out the `if (steep)` condition, so this is the code for the case when the slope of the line is less than 1. `rfpart` is `1-fpart`, and `fpart` is the fractional part. `ipart` is the integer part.

I just have no idea what this calculation is supposed to be doing, and I can't find any explanations online. I can see that `yend` is the y-coordinate of the line above `xend`, and `xend` is the x coordinate of the pixel that the starting point `(x0, y0)` is inside of. Why are we even bothering to calculate `yend`? It's as if we're extending the line until the nearest integer x-coordinate.

I realize that we're coloring both the pixel that the endpoint is in, and the pixel either immediately above or below it, using certain intensities. I just don't understand the logic behind where those intensities come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Xiaolin Wu algorithm (and sub-pixel rendering techniques in general) we imagine that the screen is a continuous geometric plane, and each pixel is a 1x1 square region of that plane. We identify the *centers* of the pixels as being the points with integer coordinates.

First, we find the so-called "major axis" of the line, the axis along which the line is longest. Let's say that it's the x axis. We now loop across each one-pixel-wide column that the line passes through. For each column, we find the point on the line which is at the *center* of that column, i.e. such that the x-axis is an integer. We imagine there's a 1x1 square centered at that point. That square will completely fill the width of that column and will overlap two different pixels. We color each of those pixels according to the *area* of the overlap between the square and the pixel.

For the endpoints, we do things slightly differently: we still draw a square centered at the place where the line crosses the centerline of the column, *but* we cut that square off in the horizontal direction at the endpoint of the line. This is illustrated below.

[image]

This is a zoomed-in view of four pixels. The black crosses represent the centers of those pixels, and the red line is the line we want to draw. The red circle `(x0, y0)` is the starting point for the line, the line should extend from that point off to the right.

You can see the grey squares centered on the red crosses. Each pixel is going to be colored according to the area of overlap with those squares. However, in the left-hand column, we cut-off the square at x-coordinate `x0`. In light grey you can see the entire square, but only the part in dark grey is used for the area calculation. There are probably other ways we could have handled the endpoints, for instance we could have shifted the dark grey region up a bit so it's vertically centered at the y-coordinate `y0`. Presumably it doesn't make much visible difference, and this is computationally efficient.

I've annotated the drawing using the names of variables from the pseudocode on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is approximate at endpoints. This is justified because exact computation would be fairly complex (and depend on the type of endpoint), for a result barely perceivable. What matters is aliasing along the segment.